# Multiple pagination in single page

Tags: css, pagination, codeigniter-3

I create a script for multiple pagination in single page for codeigniter but both the link of pagination active same tag, suppose for first I'm on 3rd page and for second I am on first page but both active on 3rd link.Please help me to solve this.

Here is my code, for first pagination

```
 $config1 = array();
 $config1["base_url"] = base_url();
 $config1["total_rows"] = $this->admin_model->record_count($query1);
 $config1["per_page"] = 30;
 $config1["uri_segment"] = 4;
 $config1['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
 $choice = 3;
 $config1["num_links"] = floor($choice);          
 $config1['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
 $config1['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
 $config1['first_link'] = 'First';
 $config1['last_link'] = 'Last';
 $config1['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
 $config1['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
 $config1['prev_link'] = '«';
 $config1['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
 $config1['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
 $config1['next_link'] = '»';
 $config1['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
 $config1['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
 $config1['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
 $config1['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
 $config1['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
 $config1['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
 $config1['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
 $config1['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
 $config1['prefix'] = "/".$this->uri->segment(3)."/";
 $config1['suffix'] = "";
 $config1['first_url'] = base_url() ."/".$this->uri->segment(3)."/0/";
 $this->pagination->initialize($config1);
 $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? (($this->uri->segment(4)*$config1["per_page"])-$config1["per_page"]) : 0;
            $queryLimit =" LIMIT $page, {$config1["per_page"]}";

    $form['my_survey']=$this->admin_model->getRecordQuery($query1.$queryLimit);
            $form["links1"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

For second pagination

```
$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = base_url();
$config["total_rows"] = $this->admin_model->record_count($query2);
$config["per_page"] = 5;
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$choice = 3;
$config["num_links"] = floor($choice);          
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination1">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '«';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '»';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prefix'] = "";
$config['suffix'] = "/".$this->uri->segment(4)."/";
$config['first_url'] = base_url()."/0/".$this->uri->segment(4)."/";
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? (($this->uri->segment(3)*$config["per_page"])-$config["per_page"]) : 0;
            $queryLimit =" LIMIT $page, {$config["per_page"]}";
                                        $form['form']=$this->admin_model->getRecordQuery($query2.$queryLimit);

$form["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Comment: Please Help me !!!

Comment: Is there any one to help me for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use server-side pagination for the multiple grid & pagination on the same page. I'm using datatable for the single grid, you can take idea from this example.

**Load view**

```
public function index(){
        if($this->session->userdata('id')){
            $search = trim($this->input->post('search'));

            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "user";
            //$config["total_rows"] = $this->user_model->count($search);
            $config["per_page"] = 20;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config['query_string_segment'] = 'per_page';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

          //  $page   = trim($this->input->post('page'));
            $data["search"] = $search;
            //$data["list"] = $this->user_model->userList($search, $page,  $config["per_page"]);
            $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            if($page > 1) {
                $data["sno"] = (($page*$config["per_page"])-$config["per_page"]);
            } else {
                $data["sno"] = 0;
            }

            $this->load->view('user', $data);
        }else{
           //load login view
            redirect(base_url());
        }
    }
```

**API Function**

```
public function list() {
        if($this->session->userdata('id')){
            $search = trim($this->input->post('search'));
            $orderColumn = (int) $_GET['order'][0]['column'];
            $orderBy = $_GET['columns'][$orderColumn]['name'];
            $orderType = $_GET['order'][0]['dir'];
            $draw = $_GET['draw'];
            $start = $_GET['start'];
            $length = $_GET['length'];

        /*/ Make search Array /*/
        //$search = array();
        $str = $_GET['search']['value'];
        if ($str != '') {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($_GET['columns']); $i++) {
                $requestColumn = $_GET['columns'][$i];
                if ($requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true') {
                    $search[$requestColumn['name']] = $str;
                }
            }
        }

        /*/ Get count of records /*/
        $recordsTotal = $this->user_model->count($search);
        $list_outlier = $this->user_model->userList($start, $length, $orderBy, $orderType, $search);

        /*/ Make data array to be display /*/
        $data = array();
        if (is_array($list_outlier) && !empty($list_outlier)) {
            $count = $start;
            /*/ If order by Serial Number with descending /*/
            if ($orderColumn == 0 && $orderType == 'desc') {
                $count = (($recordsTotal - $start) + 1 );
            }
            foreach ($list_outlier as $key => $value) {
                if ($orderColumn == 0 && $orderType == 'desc') {
                    $count--;
                } else {
                    $count++;
                }

                $data[$key][] = !empty($value->member_name)?$value->member_name:'N/A';
                $data[$key][] = !empty($value->member_type)?$value->member_type:'N/A';
                $data[$key][] = !empty($value->mobile)?$value->mobile:'N/A';
                $data[$key][] = !empty($value->email)?$value->email:'N/A';
                //$data[$key][] = !empty($value->id)?$value->id:'N/A';
                $html = '
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                 <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="getEventId('.$value->id.')" title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal5">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit
                        </a>
                    </li>';
                if($value->isActive) {
                 $html .= '<li><a href="'.base_url().'user/status?id='.$value->id.'&action=0" class="dropdown-item btn-delete" title="Deactive"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" ></i> Deactive</li>';
                } else {
                    $html .='<li><a href="'. base_url().'user/status?id='.$value->id.'&action=1" class="dropdown-item btn-delete" title="Aactive"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" ></i> Active</li>';
                 }
                $html .='</div></div>';
                $data[$key][] = $html;
            }
        }

        $respose = array(
            "draw" => ($draw + 1),
            "recordsTotal" => $recordsTotal,
            "recordsFiltered" => $recordsTotal,
            "data" => $data
        );
        echo json_encode($respose);
        }else{
            //load login view
            redirect(base_url());
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<table id="data_table_othc_dthc" class="table display table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="th-left">Name</th>
                            <th>Member Type</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th class="th-action">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        $('#data_table_othc_dthc').DataTable({
            "columns": [
                {"name": "member_name"},
                {"name": "member_type"},
                {"name": "mobile"},
                {"name": "email"},
                {"name": "id", searchable: false}
            ],
            scrollX: true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "order": [ 0, 'ASC' ],
            "ajax": "YOURDomain/user/list",
            "pageLength": 20

        });


    }); //Document End
    </script>
```

Comment: pagination works but active tag are same for both pagination link